# How do I program a custom FPS overlay in Ogre3D?

Tags: ogre

I want to make a frames per second and debugging info overlay, similar to the one in the bottom of the following image, but without using SDKTrays or OIS.

[image]

I also want to be able customize its look, by changing its font and background color. How do I program something like this, in C++?

Comment: Please choose Ogre or mOgre. They're different bindings of the same engine. You can't choose C++ and C# at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Simple+Text+Output&structure=Cookbook

Simple as adding the 40 lines class file to your project loading a font of your choice and calling 
`TextRenderer::getSingleton().printf("text", "Last FPS: %f", renderwindow->getLastFPS());` from your update method body.

Don't forget to initialize and remove the text overlay!

EDIT:

You can change it color on the initialization of the overlay:
`TextRenderer::getSingleton().addTextBox("text", "Last FPS:", 10, 10, 100, 20, Ogre::ColourValue(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaValue);`

And the font on the fontdef file.

Not sure about the background, but you can easily add another overlay behind the text modifying the addTextBox method.